# stop window scroll animation

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

can someone help me here, I need this function to stop at top: -70px;
also, when you click it anytime after its stopped it will pop back open but I think I can do that part, main question is how to stop the function I have when it reaches -70px.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var topMove = -1 * (620 * $(this).scrollTop() / $('body').height());
   $('.nav').css({ top: Math.max(topMove) });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UXZ4E/

Thanks!

Comment: When what reaches 70px exactly?

Comment: sorry I meant -70px... so if you open a browser inspector and watch the top: value change, I want it to stop changing at -70px so you will scroll down the page and the nav will dissappear but a little but will stay open for you to click and have it pop open again, by animating the top: value back to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

I had to add `console.log(topMove);` to see what value your variable was producing. In fact, it was a negative value.

I then added the following to only run when `topMove` is more than or equal to `-70`.

```
if(topMove >= -70) {
   $('.nav').css({ top: Math.max(topMove) });
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UXZ4E/1/)**

Comment: Anytime :) Don't forget to accept it as the correct answer when you can for others to see for future reference.